# Javascript - display: block/none

Tags: javascript, html, css, twig, display

Подскажите, что делаю не так. Хочу показать элемент, который скрыт.

```
<div class="admincontent3" id="admincontent3">
  Hello
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function showAddedToBasket() {
  var added_item_button = document.getElementById('admincontent3');
  var displaySetting = added_item_button.style.display;

  if (displaySetting == 'none') {
    added_item_button.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Twig:

```
{% if added_to_basket == true %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        showAddedToBasket();
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

CSS:

```
.admincontent3{
    display: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin-top: -50vw;
    -webkit-animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation: seconds 1.0s forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: У вас `display: none` задан для класса, и не задан для id. А скриптом вы проверяете состояние `display` у id.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, только не у "id", а у Dom-элемента

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы проверяете стили, присущие конкретному элементу(свойство style), в то время как display был задан в css(в классе).

---

Получить актуальные стили, с учётом всех каскадных таблиц стилей(CSS) можно с помощью функции [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
function action() {
  var added_item_button = document.getElementById('admincontent3');
  var actualDisplay = getComputedStyle(added_item_button).display;
  if (actualDisplay == 'none') {
    added_item_button.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    added_item_button.innerText += '.';
  }
}
```

```css
.admincontent3{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="admincontent3" id="admincontent3">
    Hello
 </div>
 <hr>
 <button onclick=action()>Show</button>
```